# Matlab Searching and counting through values

Tags: matlab

I have the following two matrices

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5]
B=[4 5 7 8 9 4 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 9 4 2 1 6 1 2 3 4 5 4 8 9 6 4]
```

I need to find how many times `A` repeats in `B` and which are the following 5 values after that and put in a matrix.

Eg:

```
A search through B
Ans: C = [ 1 2 3 4 5 
           8 7 9 4 2 
           4 8 9 6 4]
N = 2 % numbers of times
```

Comment: Where is the first line of `C` coming from? Is that always `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findstr` to identify the sequences, it returns the indices of the ones. The remaining stuff is just a little indexing:

```
X=findstr(A,B);
Y=arrayfun(@(X)(B(X+numel(A):X+2*numel(A)-1)),X,'uni',false);
C=cat(1,A,Y{:});
N=numel(X);
```

Comment: Or `C=[A; B(bsxfun(@plus,findstr(A,B).',numel(A):2*numel(A)-1))];` instead of `arrayfun`.

Comment: That was my initial approach. Switched to `im2col` because Daniel posted first :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo

After using the code I found that I need to find more than 5 values after the search like 7 or 9. How can I modify the code?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, using [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) *thrice*:

```
%// Data
A = [1 2 3 4 5];
B = [4 5 7 8 9 4 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 9 4 2 1 6 1 2 3 4 5 4 8 9 6 4];
H = 5;

%// Computations:
s = bsxfun(@plus, 0:numel(B)-numel(A), (1:numel(A)).'); %'
ind = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, B(s), A(:)))); %// or im2col(B(:),[numel(A) 1]) instead of B(s)
N = numel(ind);
C = B(bsxfun(@plus, ind(:)+numel(A), 0:H-1));
C = [A; C];
```

In your example:

```
>> C
C =
     1     2     3     4     5
     8     7     9     4     2
     4     8     9     6     4
>> N
N =
     2
```